# Is this possible to save the inkstroke with list or array?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, inkcanvas, filesavepicker

I'm wondering that how to save the inkstrokes with array or list and etc ways. Because I want to make inkcanvas's page with index variable.

So that user can move the page freely using the index.

For example, I want to save the all inkstrokes drawn so far (not image file), as soon as I click the next page button.

But now I can't find how to save the inkstrokes and open the saved inkstrokes

I want to save the file name and location without Filesavepicker, to keep the file name and location fixed. is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm really wondering that how to save the inkstrokes with array or list and etc ways.

You could get the `InkStroke` read only list by  [`InkStrokeContainer.GetStrokes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer.getstrokes#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStrokeContainer_GetStrokes) method and save this collection by the way you want. For example:

```
IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> strokes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
```

More details please reference [Store and retrieve Windows Ink stroke data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/save-and-load-ink).

If your purpose is for loading, you could consider to save strokes to a file, or selected all the strokes and then copy to clipboard for paste. For example:

```
private void btnreadd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.CanPasteFromClipboard())
    {
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.PasteFromClipboard(new Windows.Foundation.Point(50, 50));
    } 
}


private void btncollect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> strokes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();  
    foreach (var stroke in strokes)
    { 
        stroke.Selected = true;
    }
    inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.CopySelectedToClipboard();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying me!
but But I have more questions than your answer.
can i load the saved inkstrokes using  IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> ways on inkcanvas?

Comment: @Kay if your purpose is for re-loading, you could consider to save strokes to a file, or selected all the strokes for paste.  I will update the reply to add details.

Comment: Sunteen Thank you so much, your reply is really helpful!